# sidebar not showing in the right place until the loading of the site finish

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, sidebar

i am a beginner in javascript, and in wordpress.

i have the template Detube, which i want to modify. i have to make the sidebar semi fixed and the scroll infinite.

those modification are made but it doesn't work  in the way that i want. The sidebar, appears on the left when oppening the site, and after few seconds it regains its place on the right. you can see the result here
 i want to fix that issue

the code of the script is below

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $=javascript.noConflict(); 
    $(document).scroll(function() {

        var scrollPosition = $(document).scrollTop();
        var scrollReference = 2100;
        if (scrollPosition >= scrollReference) {      
            $('#dpe_fp_widget-4').css('position', 'fixed');  
            $('#dpe_fp_widget-4').css('top', '100px');
            $('#dpe_fp_widget-4').css('left', 'initial');  

            $('#dpe_fp_widget-5').css('position', 'fixed');  
            $('#dpe_fp_widget-5').css('top', '100px');
            $('#dpe_fp_widget-5').css('left', 'initial');  

            $('#text-6').css('position', 'fixed');  
            $('#text-6').css('top', '550px');
            $('#text-6').css('left', 'initial'); 

            $('#text-7').css('position', 'fixed');  
            $('#text-7').css('top', '550px');
            $('#text-7').css('left', 'initial');

        } else {
            $('#dpe_fp_widget-4').css('position', 'absolute');  
            $('#dpe_fp_widget-4').css('top', '841px');
            $('#dpe_fp_widget-4').css('left', '0px');  

            $('#dpe_fp_widget-5').css('position', 'absolute');  
            $('#dpe_fp_widget-5').css('top', '841px');
            $('#dpe_fp_widget-5').css('left', '0px');  

            $('#text-6').css('position', 'absolute');  
            $('#text-6').css('top', '1291px');
            $('#text-6').css('left', '0px'); 

            $('#text-7').css('position', 'absolute');  
            $('#text-7').css('top', '1291px');
            $('#text-7').css('left', '0px');
        };  
    });

});
```

i call the script in the file function.php

```php
function my_loader_jquery() {

    if( !is_admin()){
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js', false, '');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }
}

add_action('init', 'my_loader_jquery'); 

function theme_js() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'sidebar-fixe', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/sidebar-fixe.js', array() );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'infinite-scroll', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/infinite-scroll.js', array() );

}
```

in the css

```
#sidebar {
    width:336px;
    float:right;
}


/*== Sidebar
 *=================================*/
#sidebar .widget{width:300px; padding-top: 30px;}
```

Note:Please excuse my english

Comment: That's too much code for simple functionality. No wonder browser is confused too.

Comment: did you mean that the script is too long?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to call the script on `window.load()` instead of `ready()`.

Comment: I think this answer *could* indeed be valid if there only would be more info: Where? What? Why? How?

Comment: it worked! thank you Pradeep Rana! , but it is slow how can i make it more speed to load

Answer (score 0):

try adding position: relative on #sidebar .widget
in css:

```
#sidebar .widget {
      width: 300px;
      padding-top: 30px;
      position: relative;
}
```

Comment: any other suggestion?